# Ruby: Put one message if the while loop breaks and another message if the while loop ends

Tags: ruby, while-loop, break

Starting out with Ruby and doing an exercise I found online. Originally, it was just to make a script that generates a random number and lets the user guess what it is, with feedback as to whether the guess is too high "Hot" or too low "Cold".

I wanted to add to this by giving the user only 5 guesses. So I want is for the script to say "Correct! You win!" if the user guesses correctly, but say "Sorry, you lose. The correct answer was #{answer}." if you use up all your guesses.

My code:

```
answer = rand(1..100)
guess_count = 5

puts answer

print "Pick a number between 1 and 100. You get 5 guesses. "
guess = gets.chomp.to_i

while guess_count > 1
  guess_count -= 1
  break puts "Correct! You win!" if guess == answer
  if guess > answer
    print "Hot. "
  else
    print "Cold. "
  end
  puts guess_count != 1 ? "Guess again. You have #{guess_count} guesses left." : "Guess again. You have 1 guess left."
  guess = gets.chomp.to_i
end puts "Sorry, you lose. The correct answer was #{answer}."
```

But this doesn't work because you can't tack that "puts" line on the end of "end" like you can with "break". Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning the string to a variable and printing it at the end of the loop?

```
output = "Sorry, you lose. The correct answer was #{answer}."
while guess_count > 1
  guess_count -= 1
  if guess == answer
    output = "Correct! You win!"
    break
  end
  if guess > answer
    print "Hot. "
  else
    print "Cold. "
  end
  puts guess_count != 1 ? "Guess again. You have #{guess_count} guesses left." : "Guess again. You have 1 guess left."
  guess = gets.chomp.to_i
end
puts output
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets the job done. I guess I was more interested in if there was any way to have all on one line "This happens when it reaches the end of the loop, but is ignored if the loop is exited early". But I guess that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this

```
def guess_number
  number, attempts = rand(1..100), 5

  while attempts != 0
    attempts -= 1
    puts "Your's guess ?"
    guess = gets.chomp.to_i
    if number == guess
      return "Correct! You win!"
    else
      if attempts != 0
        puts number < guess ? "Cold." : "Hot."
        puts "Guess again. You have #{attempts} attempts left."
      end
    end
  end
  "Sorry, you lose. The correct answer was #{number}."
end
```